# Why does std::atomic's compare_exchange take a reference for the expected value?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

What is the reason for `std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_*` taking the expected value by reference, instead of taking it by value?

Comment: Because when you take it by value a copy is made.

Comment: Because `expected` is an out-value when `expected != *this`

Comment: While a pointer would work, references disallows null pointers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`compare_exchange_*` changes `expected` to actual value if operation fails. It makes loops a bit simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a common usage pattern:

```
atomic<int> foo;

int expected = 3;
while(!foo.compare_exchange_strong(expected, 4)) {
    // somebody beat us to it
    // now decided what to do; break the loop? try again?
    if (expected == 4) {
        // somebody already wrote a 4 there
        break;
    } // otherwise keep trying
}
```

It *could* return a `pair<bool,T>` instead, but it would be less convenient for this use case. It *could* return the value in another argument, but you would have to copy into `expected` manually before you tried again.

IMHO this is a good trade-off, even though it won't let you pass a constant in the first argument (as it's a rare use case).

Comment: Another common pattern is `int expected = foo.load(relaxed);` / `int desired;` / `do{ desired = f(expected); }while(!foo.CAS(expected, desired));` to synthesize an atomic RMW.